# Link won't show using the_permalink();

Tags: theme-development, loop, permalinks

Inside my loop, I'm trying to have a link show and it won't I'm not sure why

Here is the code:

```
<?php the_title('<h2 class="wow"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"', '</a></h2>'); ?>
```

I understand this is maybe because of the `''` quotations instead of `""`, but how would I achieve this general thing with just PHP and not by wrapping `the_title();` in an a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `the_title()` expects a string for the `$before` and `$after` args, you need to use the string version of the permalink, in a string concatenation;

`<?php the_title('<h2 class="wow"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">', '</a></h2>');  ?>`

you also had a missing `>`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: I eventually found the answer elsewhere. THANK YOU. This is pretty much what the answer said to do. The only difference was that it escaped the permalink instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest these functions. Change your code to

```
<h2 class="wow"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

23 seconds too late.

I think the issue is that you have a double  open/close statement.

Without seeing your code, I would suggest you to edit your line of code as

```
<h2 class="wow"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```